# Importing sql dump file into PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Here is what I am dealing with, and I apologize for not being very sure of what I am doing.

I am trying to import a sql database dump file into xampp so that I can run a friends application.

I cloned the repository and put the code base into my htdocs folder. However, it needs to communicate with the database to run.

I have the dump file however when I go to import it I get the following:

> ```
> Error
> SQL query:
>
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sl_address`
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1046 - No database selected
> ```

Do I need to create a database to dump into before I import the sql dump file? If so, does it matter what I name it, if it does how do I know what to name it? 
I imagine if I don't name it correctly that the application won't be able to communicate with it.

I am really new to all this so I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a database and select it before you run the SQL script that was generated by the dump.

Something like this:

```
create database newdb;
use newdb;
```

then the rest of your script.

Bobby